# How to create circular relationships in django-filter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Using django-filters, I have judgements written by judges. The models are roughly:

**app1: models.py:**

```
from app2.models import Judge
class Judgement(model.Models):
    judges = models.ManyToManyField(Judge, related_name="judgements")
    topic = models.TextField(help_text="The topic the judgement is about."
```

**app2: models.py**

```
class Judge(models.Models):
    name = CharField(max_length=100)
    race = CharField(max_length=5, choices=RACES)
```

I want to be able to filter Judgements or Judges by one or the other, so my filters should be:

```
class JudgementFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    # THIS DOESN'T WORK. 
    judges = RelatedFilter('JudgeFilter', name='judges')

class JudgeFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    judgements = RelatedFilter(JudgementFilter, name='judgements')
```

If that worked, I'd be able to ask the API for Judges filtered by attributes of the judgements they wrote (For example: "all judges writing a judgement about race"), or I'd be able to filter for Judgements filtered by the Judges that wrote them (For example, "all judgements written by black judges").

Unfortunately, this doesn't work and I get an error about trying to import the string value instead of something else. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you include the traceback for your error here? Also, is this the full code? Also, what is `RelatedFilter`? I can't find a reference to that in django-filter.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @JoeyWilhelm. I forgot to mention this is django-rest-framework-filters, not the usual django-filters, but anyway, I figured it out in the most idiotic way possible (see below). I sent a PR to tweak the docs to make this info more prominent in the future. Hopefully others will benefit from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I regret to answer my own question this way, but [this information was in the readme](https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters/blob/master/README.rst) and I totally missed it.

The solution is to use full paths:

```
class JudgementFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    judges = RelatedFilter('path.to.my.app.JudgeFilter', name='judges')

class JudgeFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    judgements = RelatedFilter(JudgementFilter, name='judgements')
```

And then life is good.

Comment: Are you sure that second one is correct? The `judgements` filter appears to be referring to itself.

Comment: Right you are, again! Thanks.